# Script for counting weekends

Tags: shell, date

Script for counting weekends (saturdays AND sundays) in a given month, by passing in month and year. How to write it?

New in scripting, can't find solution to this easy task.

Comment: If the 1st of the month is a Sunday, or the last day of the month is a Saturday, do they count as weekends?

Comment: Are you permitted to call any programs (such as cal or awk), or must this be done solely with shell builtin functions?

Comment: What type of shell is this, and what is this for?

Answer (score 0):

You want to count weekends Sat and Sun, So I am guessing you mean 2 day weekends.
Hope this helps.  VonBell

1. In unix/linux you can easily parse the cal command for the given month.

   $ cal 04 2013
    April 2013
   Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
   ... 1  2  3  4  5  6
    7  8  9 10 11 12 13
   14 15 16 17 18 19 20
   21 22 23 24 25 26 27
   28 29 30
2. The numerical date always start on Line 3, the cols for each day are constant
   When I used the commands below to extract the weekend (sun, Sat)
   As you can see Sun is cols 1,2,3 (with space included) and Sat is cols 19,20

   $ cal 04 2013|tail +3|cut -c1-3,19,20
   ..  6
    7 13
   14 20
   21 27
   28
3. When I execute the script below as cntWkEnd.sh The output is as follows
   1 equals one day wkend and 2 equals 2 day wkend sat and sun

   $ ./cntWkEnd.sh 04 2013
    1
    2
    2
    2
    1
    0
4. To count only 2 day weekends you can add at the command line or in the script
   the following

   ./cntWkEnd.sh 04 2013|grep "2"|wc -l (Output of 3 shown below)
     3

This the contents of cntWkEnd.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
cal $1 $2|tail +3|cut -c1-3,19,20 |\
while read WkEnd
do
echo $WkEnd|wc -w
done
```

Comment: something about numbered entries seems to defeat quoting code. In general, use the `{}` tool at the top of the text input box to keep code formatted correctly, or surround each block with blank lines and indent for (at least) 4 spaces. Keep posting!

Comment: Thanks shelter, I will try to do better, new at posting code to help others.